# List in recyclerview not sorting

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I have a list of pairs of phone numbers and messages in a database. I want to sort the list by phone number or message text in reverse order after pressing the respective button in the options menu.

I implemented `Collections.sort` with `compare` and updated the adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. However, when I press the buttons, nothing happens. As a test, I tried calling the sorting method and `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of `onViewCreated()`, but that didn't sort, either.

```
public class LogScreen extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int LOG_LOADER_ID = 0;
    private LogAdapter mLogAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    List<LogEntryItem> mLogList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log_screen, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_log);

        int recyclerViewOrientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;
        boolean shouldReverseLayout = false;

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), recyclerViewOrientation, shouldReverseLayout);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mLogAdapter = new LogAdapter(getContext(), mLogList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLogAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOG_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_log_screen, menu);

        MenuItem buttonSortByPhone   = menu.findItem(R.id.log_screen_sort_by_phone);
        MenuItem buttonSortByMessage = menu.findItem(R.id.log_screen_sort_by_message);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.log_screen_sort_by_phone:
                reverseSortComparePhoneNumber();
                return true;

            case R.id.log_screen_sort_by_message:
                reverseSortCompareMessageSent();
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void reverseSortComparePhoneNumber() {

        Collections.sort(mLogList, new Comparator<LogEntryItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LogEntryItem itemA, LogEntryItem itemB) {
                return itemB.getPhoneNumber().compareTo(itemA.getPhoneNumber());
            }
        });

        mLogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void reverseSortCompareMessageSent() {

        Collections.sort(mLogList, new Comparator<LogEntryItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LogEntryItem itemA, LogEntryItem itemB) {
                return itemB.getMessageSent().compareTo(itemA.getMessageSent());
            }
        });

        mLogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), LogContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        List<LogEntryItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogDBHelper.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogDBHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE);

            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(index1);
            String messageSent = cursor.getString(index2);

            LogEntryItem logEntry = new LogEntryItem(phoneNumber, messageSent);
            list.add(logEntry);
        }

        mLogAdapter = new LogAdapter(getContext(), list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLogAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

}
```

Why isn't `Collections.sort` sorting my list?

Comment: Cant it be because of the code in the `onLoadFinished`? Im not into the loaders, but there you set an adapter for recycler view passing local variable `list`. It means that after this code is called, your adapter is not bound to `mLogList` anymore

Comment: Thank you, @Teempy! Yes, I mistakenly used that local variable `list` in `onLoadFinished` instead of the global `mLogList`. I made that change, and it works perfectly! (If you make an Answer from your comment, I will accept it. Thank you.)

Comment: Glad it helped, I'd appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant it be because of the code in the `onLoadFinished`? Im not into the Loaders, but there you set an adapter for recycler view passing local variable `list`. It means that after this code is called, your adapter is not bound to `mLogList` anymore.

Comment: As stated above in a comment off the original post.... Thank you, @Teempy! Yes, I mistakenly used that local variable `list` in `onLoadFinished` instead of the global `mLogList`. I made that change, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For reverse lexicographically sorting your LogEntryItem messages:

```
class SortbyMessage implements Comparator<LogEntryItem> { 
    @Override
    public int compare(LogEntryItem a, LogEntryItem b) { 
        return a.getMessageSent().compareTo(b.getMessageSent());
    } 
}
```

Now you can use this like so

```
Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder(new SortbyMessage()); 
Collections.sort(ar, comparator);
```

For number sorting similar as above except

```
return a.getPhoneNumber() - b.getPhoneNumber();
```

or in your reverseSortComparePhoneNumber method change your return to

```
itemB.getPhoneNumber() - itemA.getPhoneNumber();
```

Comment: This didn't help at all. Assuming "`ar`" in `Collections.sort(ar, comparator)` is my array list (`mLogList`), I'm pretty sure this is effectively the same as what I already have in the `reverseSortCompareMessageSent()` method.